# How to display a defined value

Tags: doxygen, c-preprocessor

In some doxygen documentation I'd like to display the content of a `#define`, not the tag itself. For instance, in a C file I have

```
#define REPEAT_N_TIMES 10
```

Now in my documentation I want to display:

> The action is done 10 times.

If I use `\ref REPEAT_N_TIMES`, it displays:

> The action is done REPEAT_N_TIMES times

Is there a way to display the *content* of a link, not the link itself, for example like `\ValueOf(\ref REPEAT_N_TIMES)` or `\contentOf(\ref REPEAT_N_TIMES)`?

**Update:** My Doxygen's config is:

```
// Configuration options related to the preprocessor

ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           =
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  =
PREDEFINED             = WXUNUSED()=
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      =
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES
```

The `MACRO_EXPANSION` setting seems to change the "details" of the macros. But I don't see a way to select either the name of the macro, or its content. Using the command `\ref` doesn't seems to be the right way: it refers to "something" not the content of "something"

Is there an operator or function I could use, possibly similar to **C**, where I can use something like `\ref *something` instead of `\ref something`?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1510919/623518 Essentially, *comments are replaced with a single space in the "translation phase", which happens prior to the Preprocessing directive parsing*. So preprocessing **cannot** be used to replace directives within comments. The only way to do this is to use the input filter, as I suggest in my answer. Alternatively, just reference your define (see my update).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299608/expand-non-function-macros-in-doxygen-documentation-for-c

Answer (score 0):

The doxygen manual page on [preprocessing](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html) seems to have all the information you need. As a first step try setting the `MACRO_EXPANSION` flag in the doxygen configuration file to `YES`, then in your documentation include

```
The action is done REPEAT_N_TIMES times.
```

As noted in the doxygen manual, this will expand all macro definitions (recursively if needed), which is often too much. Therefore you can specify exactly which macros to expand using the `EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF` and `EXPAND_AS_DEFINED` settings in the configuration file. For example, try setting

> EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF = YES
>   EXPAND_AS_DEFINED = REPEAT_N_TIMES

in the configuration file.

**UPDATE:** Following @spamy's comment I looked into this a bit more and it seems that the methods I have mentioned above does not work for macros *within* comment blocks, i.e. only macros within the source code are expanded. See, for example, [this post](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=11649789) on the doxygen sourceforge page. According to this post the only way to achieve macro expansion within comment blocks is to use the `INPUT_FILTER` configuration file setting. Use something like

```
INPUT_FILTER = sed /REPEAT_N_TIMES/10
```

**Warning:** The above `INPUT_FILTER` has not been tested.

If you don't want to use the `INPUT_FILTER` then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9299914/623518) answer to another thread is probably your best bet. Essentially it says *you can document the macro, so readers of the documentation would be able to find the real value easily*. So add documentation to your `#define` and just `\ref` it elsewhere in your documentation.

Comment: My config is: #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the preprocessor
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           =
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  =
PREDEFINED             = WXUNUSED()=
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      =
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES

Comment: Ok, it seems that macro expansion within comment blocks is only possible by using `INPUT_FILTER`, see my update.